# Why is valgrind reporting two memory allocations when my code only requests one?

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

When I run the following program through valgrind (`valgrind ./a.out --leak-check=yes`):

```cpp
int main() {
    char* ptr = new char;
    return 0;
}
```

the report contains this:

```
==103== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
==103==
==103== HEAP SUMMARY:
==103==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==103==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,705 bytes allocated
==103==
==103== LEAK SUMMARY:
==103==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==103==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==103== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

What's the extra 72,704-byte allocation valgrind is reporting? It seems to be taken care of before the program is over, so I'm guessing it's something the compiler is doing. I'm using gcc on an Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10.

Edit: The memory leak was intentional in this example, but I get similar messages about an extra allocation regardless of whether or not there's a leak.

Comment: Is that your entire program or do you have any includes?

Comment: @JohnFilleau That's the whole program (50 bytes). I had thought iostream might have had something to do with it, but the extra allocation is still there without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you surmise, the extra allocation is part of the runtime, and it is correctly cleaned up as you can see in Valgrind's output. Don't worry about it.

If you're asking specifically what it is, you'll have to read the C++ runtime library of your specific compiler and version (`libc` since you're using `gcc`). But again, it shouldn't concern you.